# How do I train tesseract to ignore the wavy lines added from spelling and grammar error detection?

Tags: imagemagick, tesseract-ocr

I am using tesseract to detect text in a variety of image types, including screenshots, it's getting confused by the wavy red and blue underlines for spelling and grammar warnings, like the example below. I end up getting either no text or a garbled mess.

[image]

I have looked at ways to eliminate these lines in imagemagick pre-processing with some success, but these methods wipe out any text which is red or blue, which is undesirable - plus they take a long time to run and I need to process over 100k images per day. I am thinking that maybe there is a way to train tesseract to recognize and discard these lines, but I'm not sure how that would work.

I have seen tutorials on how to train tesseract to recognize text, but I haven't seen anything how how to train to recognize something that isn't text. Is there a way I can train tesseract, or do something with the Leptonica setup it uses, to ignore these lines?

If anyone has successfully dealt with this please let me know, otherwise what would the recommended approach be?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently trying to learn how to teach tesseract(im stuck on how to create lstm files for training), but i know that you can Fine tune your trained data. I use [jTessBoxEditor](http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html) for correcting the misteaks tesseract does during OCR, i just haven't found a way to implement the changes in a form of training, but that tool is just what you need, I think.

Using jTessBoxEditor you can see how is the OCR done on your picture, also you can edit it, but im still stuck on how to implement the training (Still waiting on response on the forum and also here) so i cant really help more, because thats how far i got and i wouldnt expect anyone to answer on your question as it is 2 years old, so your  setup probably already outdated. Im trying tesseract-ocr 4.* and teaching in new version changed a lot, but also the tools evolved too, so your problem is doable with jTessBoxEditor, but i dont know how to implement it so this is not really an answer but just a partial.

I hope i could help you even if just a little bit.

Comment: Sorry about that. The link for the said tool has the exact page where it describes how to set the box tesseract recognises.

Comment: Link also includes pictures and how to download